# Empty set in type script

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I have a theoretical question. Is there a way to design a type in TypeScript that denotes the empty set?
I tried define one using union, disjoint union, intersection and more...

Comment: Theoretically answer would lie in boolean. :) BTW what do you consider. An empty interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although I think the usefulness of such a type depends a lot on your style of programming. You could define `EmptySet` like this:

```
interface ISet { 
    intersection: (s: ISet) => ISet;
    union: (s: ISet) => ISet;
}

class EmptySet implements ISet { 
    intersection(s: ISet) { 
        return this;
    }

    union(s: ISet) { 
        return s;
    }
}

class NonEmptySet implements ISet { ... }
```

`ISet` is the generic contract of a set, `EmptySet` is a concrete type that implements that contract. Obviously a you can do more things with a set than `union` and `intersection`, this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks, could you pleas explain why something like this doesn't work:   
   type Z = { a: number } & { a: string };

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: I expect it to be an empty set, since a can't be both,a number and a string.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how types work in Typescript. `{}` doesn't denote a set in TS. I recommend reading he handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html